# What "bugs" are there in Eternal Duelist Soul?

Tags: yu-gi-oh-eternal-duelist-soul

So I have started playing this games again, and I have started to notice that after a while, most opponents will seem to "know" what cards I have face down on the table.

For example, one card I always deploy is *Wall of Illusion*, which has a special effect that the card attacking it will be returned to the owner's hand. Another one I use is *Needle Worm*, that when flipped, it discards the top 5 cards from the opponent's deck; and *Skelengel*, which allows me to draw a card when flipped.

The last 2 have low attack and defense values, and can be easily destroyed, and the effect doesn't seem to be too big of an issue. *Wall of Illusion* however, has a defense value of 1850, and even when it is placed face down, if I have all 3 of these on the table, the opponent will attack the other 2, but leave *Wall of Illusion* untouched, regardless of what is currently on the table; as if they know what the card is.

Is this a (known) bug? If so, what other bugs are there in the game that I should be aware of?

Comment: Yeah, after a certain difficulty point, computer players will know the defense value of your facedown monsters.  I'm not sure it's a bug as much as a way to keep a relatively simple AI challenging.

Comment: Heart of the Cards, working as intended.